# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Here's the code I'm using (Oracle database connectivity):

```
try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@loclahost:1521:XE","system","system");
        System.out.println("connection is established");
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        int i=stmt.executeUpdate("insert table students ( name varchar2(15),mobile number(10),age varchar2(1))");
        System.out.println("Save Sucessfully");
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
this.dispose();
```

Getting following Error:

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
>   not establish the connection

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please show us your stack trace? Without this it is difficult to determine you concrete problem.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a typo in your connection string - use `localhost` instead of `loclahost`

Answer (score 2):

use `localhost` in DriverManager.getConnection

Here is the code :

```
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","system");
    System.out.println("connection is established");
    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
    int i=stmt.executeUpdate("insert table students ( name varchar2(15),mobile number(10),age varchar2(1))");
    System.out.println("Save Sucessfully");
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
 }
  this.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error could occur if your JDBC driver is unable to connect to oracle. Check if your oracle service is running and no firewall is blocking  your connection.

Check if oracle is listening in port 1521 or not, if not fix the port issue and then try connecting to your database.

Collectively the things to check ,

> Check if the listener service is running
>
> No firewall is blocking
>
> Your service is listening on the correct port number that you
>   specified in your code.