# Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

I have a problem with a spring boot application. I have a database connection to an Oracle DB on the cloud. The application works when I run the app in local, but when I deploy the application to the cloud the application start well, but it cannot connect to the Oracle DB.

The error that displays the app is: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Application properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.username=myuser 
spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip>:<port>:cdb1
```

EDITED:

The problem appears when I changed to a new user created with the next script:

```
connect sys as sysdba
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED BY mypass;
GRANT CONNECT TO myuser;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO myuser;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO myuser ;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO myuser
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377764/java-sql-sqlrecoverableexception-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-co)

Comment: Is not duplicated. this issue talk about an error on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a IP whitelist and your local machine is whitelisted, but your cloud host is not.

Can you ssh to the cloud host and ping this cloud db?

Comment: Any solutions for this problem?